# Printing from web page…

Tags: asp.net

The application is ASP.Net Web Forms on .net 4.5

I have a data entry form with few buttons on it(Save, Create Next Record etc….)

I can’t use the buitin function of print(right click print or browser print menu) because it prints everything it displays on the screen and the screen display resolution/settings is not good for printing.

One approach is to create a new web page with the data I want to print and the user can print from there.

Is there any other solution?

Answer (score 4):

Use the built-in JavaScript `print` function, with a print-only stylesheet:

- In your existing stylesheet: `@media print`, or
- In the HTML:

  ```
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="print" href="print.css" />
  ```

More:

- http://www.alistapart.com/articles/goingtoprint
- http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2011/11/24/how-to-set-up-a-print-style-sheet